# Having Trouble Formalizing a Combinatorial Argument

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, solution-verification, convex-analysis, affine-geometry

Let $\{X_i\}_{i = 1} ^d$ be symmetric linearly independent i.i.d random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I wish to show
$$
\mathbb{P}\{  0 \in \mathrm{conv}\{ X_i \}_{i \in I}| 0 \in \mathrm{aff}\{ X_i \}_{i \in I}  \} = \frac{1}{2^{d - 1}}.
$$
**My Attempt:**
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\{ 0 \in \mathrm{conv}\{ X_i \}_{i \in I}| 0 \in \mathrm{aff}\{ X_i \}_{i \in I}  \} &= \mathbb{P}\{ 0 \in \mathrm{conv}\{ X_i \}_{i \in I}| 0 \in \mathrm{aff}\{ X_i \}_{i \in I} \} \\
    &= \mathbb{P}\{ 0 \in \mathrm{conv}\{ X_i \}_{i \in I} | 0 \in \mathrm{aff}\{ X_i \}_{i \in I}, \mathrm{coef}(\mathrm{aff}(X_i)) \geq 0 \} \\
    &+ \mathbb{P}\{ 0 \in \mathrm{conv}\{ -X_i \}_{i \in I} | 0 \in \mathrm{aff}\{ X_i \}_{i \in I}, \mathrm{coef}(\mathrm{aff}(X_i)) \leq 0 \} \\
    &= 2\mathbb{P}\{ 0 \in \mathrm{conv}\{ X_i \}_{i \in I} | 0 \in \mathrm{aff}\{ X_i \}_{i \in I}, \mathrm{coef}(\mathrm{aff}(X_i)) \geq 0 \} \\
    &= \frac{1}{2^{d - 1}}.
\end{align*}
I am not sure if I can pass to the second equality as I claimed here.

Comment: what is a symmetric vector?

Comment: @Exodd It is symmetically distributed. That is, the distribution of $X$ and $-X$ is the same.

Comment: By $\mathrm{coef}(\mathrm{aff}(X_i)) \geq 0$ do you mean a single $i$ or each $i \in I$?

Comment: @VezenBU I meant all of $i \in I$.